# timediff() from mysql select

Tags: mysql, calendar

I have a table (calendar) which is basically a calendar with additional info about custom holidays and shortened workdays. calendar rows columns are as follows: id,date,dayofweek,short,holiday

I am trying to use datediff to calculate available workingdays but i cannot even get the datediff() working as i would like it to work.

select datediff(date1,date2) from (select (select date from calendar where id='1') as date1, (select date from calendar where id='396') as date2);

ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

I cannot get my head around it, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't alias the outer table:

```
select datediff(date1,date2) 
from (
    select 
        (select date from calendar where id='1') as date1,
        (select date from calendar where id='396') as date2
) as outertable
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid simple. thanks alot.